# $N(s) = 1$ if and only if s is a unit if and only if $s = \pm 1$ or $\pm i$. $s \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, gaussian-integers

I'm confused. This is a homework question and I am not asking for the answer, but I was just wondering if I have to prove the second iff then use that to prove the first iff. Either that or my professor is confused.

Comment: Did he put brackets anywhere? This could be interpreted in a number of ways.

Comment: This is exactly how it has been given.

Comment: Then I would think you have to prove equivalence between the three propositions separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $ z=x+iy \in\mathbb{C} $
then $ N[s]=1 \Rightarrow x^{2}+y^{2}=1 $

$\Rightarrow (x^{2}=1$ and  $y^{2}=0)$ or $ (x^{2}=0$ and  $y^{2}=1)$

Because x,y are integer.

If $x^{2}=1 
\Rightarrow x=1$ or $x=-1$

Thus, $z_{1}=1$ or $z_{2}=-1$

If $y^{2}=1 
\Rightarrow y=1$ or $y=-1$

Thus, $z_{3}=i$ or $z_{4}=-i$

Comment: By mistake i wanted to write $z=x+iy \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$