# How would I go about finding $\theta$ and suggesting an unbiased estimator?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, parameter-estimation

> a) Suppose $N$ is a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda$. Show that $E[(1+a)]^N]=e^{a\lambda}$ for any constant $a$.
>
> b) Telephone calls enter a switchboard in a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$ every $10$ minutes. In a 10 minute period, $N$ calls enter the switchboard. In order to decide whether he can chance an unofficial tea-break, the operator wants to estimate the probability $\theta$ that there will be no incoming calls in the next $20$ minutes, using this single observation
> $N$.
>
> Write down an expression for $\theta$ in terms of $\lambda$. Use this, together with the result in part (a), to suggest an unbiased estimator $T(N)$ of $\theta$. Is this estimator sensible?

I have done the first part of the question but I am unsure on how to find $\theta$ in the next part and how to find an estimator. I am thinking that I should set $\alpha$ to be something but I am unclear on how these estimators work.

Comment: Please don't use pictures. Use MathJax as for your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521245/ns-1-if-and-only-if-s-is-a-unit-if-and-only-if-s-pm-1-or-pm-i-s).

Comment: My bad, someone else edited that question for me. Only just learnt to use Latex.

Comment: Use the MathJax [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), that's easier.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that there are no calls in the next $20$ minutes is simply $\Pr[N(2) = 0] = e^{-2\lambda}$, where $N(t) \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ is the random number of calls in $t$ time increments of $10$ minutes.  So $$\theta = e^{-2\lambda}$$ is the desired relationship.  This would seem to suggest letting $a = -2$ in part (a), which would give you $$\operatorname{E}[(-1)^N] = e^{-2\lambda} = \theta,$$ and so the estimator $$T(N) = (-1)^N$$ is unbiased for $\theta$.  But when it comes to asking whether it's a *good* estimator, is it?  It would mean that if $N$ is odd, you would choose $\theta = -1$, whereas if $N$ is even, you would choose $\theta = 1$, and since $\theta$ is a *probability*--remember, it is the probability of no calls in the next $20$ minutes--this is an awful choice for an estimator.

Is there a better estimator we can choose, even if it is possibly biased?

Comment: What makes an estimator good in general?

Comment: @kiryuchan123 Certainly, an estimator that stays in the support of the parameter of interest would be preferable to one that does not.  There are other criteria, such as whether it is biased, consistent, or efficient.  In this case, can you think of an estimator that always gives a result between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: I'm not quite sure on how to choose an estimator.